# Has column type of complex type in ef core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

I want to change column type of property using fluent api, but i have an error

*The expression 'x => x.NestedProp.Prop1' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.*

**please, i dont want to use DataAnnotations**

Here is my code (Classes):

```
public class Class1 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public NestedProp NestedProp { get; set; } = new NestedProp();
}

public class NestedProp {
     public decimal Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

And **OnModelCreating:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>(e =>
            {
                e.OwnsOne(t => t.NestedProp);
                e.Property(p => p.NestedProp.Prop1).HasColumnType("NUMERIC(38, 16)");
            });
}
```

Comment: Configure `Prop1` on `NestedProp`, not on `Class1`.

Comment: @CodeCaster When i do this, i get another error: The entity type 'NestedProp' cannot be added to the model because a dependent entity type with the same name already exists.

Comment: Well, in my answer I thought it is only a code snipped and not the complete model, but currently I'm not sure. Therefore I added necessary PK to `NestedProp` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give the following a try and pay attention to the `Id` property in your class `NestedProp`. EF (Core) needs in every model a primary key, otherwise it will not work.

**Models**

```
public class Class1 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual NestedProp NestedProp { get; set; } = new NestedProp();
}

public class NestedProp
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public decimal Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var class1Entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>();
    class1Entity.HasOne(p => p.NestedProp);

    var nestedPropEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<NestedProp>();
    nestedPropEntity.Property(p => p.Prop1)
        .HasColumnType("NUMERIC(38, 16)"); // maybe decimal instead of numeric?
}
```

Here you will find some more [explanation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration).
You have to define the configuration for each model.

I recommend to use `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` instead of configure everything in `OnModelCreating`.

A nice introduction for using the Fluent API in EF Core would you find [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api) or [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx).

**EDIT:**

The Solution above will create two tables, because it implements two own data types. Not the in question asked complex type in on column. Therefore I will give advise for this solution too. This owned type mapping is realizable via `entity.OwnsOne(...)` method. It is also possible to split in like mentioned in this [MS doc article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting). In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#explicit-configuration) you will find how to configure it explicitly too.

Here the example with your code and fluent API:

**Models**

```
public class Class1 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual NestedProp NestedProp { get; set; } = new NestedProp();
}

public class NestedProp
{
     public decimal Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var class1Entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>();
    class1Entity.OwnsOne(
            class1 => class1.NestedProp,
            nestedProp =>
            {
                nestedProp.Property(p => p.NestedProp)
                      .HasColumnType("NUMERIC(38, 16)")
                      .HasColumnName("NestedPropValue"); // here you could add a custom name like I did or remove it and you get a generated one
            });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a comment to the question. I thought the code above was just a snippet and therefore I thought a PK for NestedProp is present. For completeness I updated my answer.

Comment: Well, adding a PK doesn't help either. And it defeats the very idea of owned types. Did you actually try this?

Comment: Yes, the code is tested and worked for me. But you are right, it's no complex type in column. I will improve the answer asap.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for the hint, I updated the answer. The 2nd approach is tested too.

Comment: Ah, that seems to be the way to do it.