# Entity Framework custom type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

When I create a model class and set id in DbContext, Entity Framework reads and writes this model data to database.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The primitive types are programmed by entity framework how to read and write. But I need a custom type named geometry. This type may be 2D or 3D geoemtry.

```
public class Point{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int Dimension { get; set; }
}
```

So when I set this POint type in MyModel the entity framework does not know how to read and write it. It will be a column in MyModel table. Point data willl be serialize binary or another method.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Point Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

For example table data will be like this:

```
Id     Name     Geometry
1      P1       POINT(10,13)
1      P2       POINT(20,30)
```

But I should override or inject somethings in Entity Framework to how to read and write my custom type. Is this possible?

Comment: In EF Core, owned types are what you are searching for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Comment: Maybe this question and answer could be helpful for you [Has column type of complex type in ef core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428325/has-column-type-of-complex-type-in-ef-core-2-0)